# No module named win32console, while running wexpect

Tags: python, expect, pexpect

I want to run wexpect (the windows port of pexpect) on my Windows 7 64-bit machine. I am getting the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\wexpect\build\lib>wexpect.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\wexpect\build\lib\wexpect.py", line 97, in <module>
    raise ImportError(str(e) + "This package was intended for Windows like operating systems.")
ImportError: No module named win32console This package requires the win32 python packages.This package was intended for Windows like operatin
g systems.
```

In the code it is failing on the following line:
`from win32console import *`

I am using Python 2.6.4. I cannot figure out how to install win32console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/

Edit to add slightly longer explanation: There's a very useful set of Windows-specific Python modules, called [PyWin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/).  I believe `win32console` is part of that.  You can either install PyWin32 on top of the standard [python.org](http://python.org/) release of Python, or you can install [ActiveState ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads/) which bundles everything you need all together.  I'm using ActivePython and I have a `win32console` module.

Comment: Installed it and linked it to my python 2.6 installation. Still the same error. Do I need to restart Python or something?

Comment: Start a new interactive Python session (by typing "python") and type the command "import win32console".  What happens?

Comment: I did, though, get a program called PythonWin. It provides a python console. In this console the win32console exists.

Comment: Just writing python from command line yielded the following result:
C:\Program Files (x86)\wexpect\build\lib>python
Python 2.6.4 (r264:75708, Oct 26 2009, 07:36:50) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from win32console import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named win32console

Comment: I suspect you have 2 (or more) different versions of Python installed.  Does wexpect ship with it's own version of Python?  You can figure out which Python you're using by typing "import sys" then "print sys.executable" - that works at Python command prompt or from a Python script.

Comment: (The reason for my suspicion is that you have "a program called PythonWin. It provides a python console. In this console the win32console exists." yet when you just type "python" you get a different version of Python which doesn't have win32console).

Answer (score 1):

Install [wexpect](https://pypi.org/project/wexpect/) with pip to install all dependencies (inluding pywin32).

`pip install wexpect`