# Python: win32console adds random characters to prompt default string

Tags: python, windows, console

I am using the following code (from here [How to put text in input line: how to ask for user input on the command line while providing a 'default' answer that the user can edit or delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30193945/how-to-put-text-in-input-line-how-to-ask-for-user-input-on-the-command-line-whi/32156249#32156249)) to prompt the user to modify a default string (on Windows):

```
import win32console

_stdin = win32console.GetStdHandle(win32console.STD_INPUT_HANDLE)

def input_def(prompt, default=''):
    keys = []
    for c in str(default):
        evt = win32console.PyINPUT_RECORDType(win32console.KEY_EVENT)
        evt.Char = c
        evt.RepeatCount = 1
        evt.KeyDown = True
        keys.append(evt)

    _stdin.WriteConsoleInput(keys)
    return input(prompt)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    name = input_def('Folder name: ', 'it works!!!')
    print()
    print(name)
```

My problem is that sometimes, one or multiple characters are added to my default string, most of the time at the beginning. That is to say, the above code would display `Folder name: Ait works!!!` for instance in the console.

My `keys` variable seems to have the correct length so I guess there is something wrong with `_stdin`. Is it when `_stdin` is initialized to `_stdin = win32console.GetStdHandle(win32console.STD_INPUT_HANDLE)`? How can I get rid of these random characters?

Comment: @eryksun that was it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `_stdin.FlushConsoleInputBuffer()` before `_stdin.WriteConsoleInput(keys)`. You could make this a default true option to flush the input buffer. Override it to false if you need to keep the existing contents.

Ideally your script should support a fallback if stdin is a disk file or pipe (e.g. an MSYS terminal) instead of a console, or at least fail gracefully in this case.